# The conversion of the varchar value '9000437060' overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded

Tags: .net, sql-server, debugging, stack-trace

I'm having trouble figuring out this stack trace, everything is moving away from .NET but because its all tied to a 2000 MSSQL sever that the IT admin isn't willing to upgrade, I still have to deal with some low priority apps that connect with it if something goes wrong. Nomrally I see only one stack, but here there seem to be two. I also can't tell which file it's wanting to me to check because the issue usually is at the top of the stack? I mainly do PHP, so a lot of this is unfamiliar to me.

**The stack(s) are here.**

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): The conversion of the varchar value '9000437060' overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1950890
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4846875
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2392
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows() +157
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout) +197
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read() +9
   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping) +78
   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue) +164
   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords) +353
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +164
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +287
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet) +94
   MV.Library.UserHandler.GetByMaryvilleID(String maryvilleID) in C:\Code\MV\MV.Library\User.cs:333

[UserException: UserHandler()::Get: UserHandler - The conversion of the varchar value '9000437060' overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded.]
   MV.Library.UserHandler.GetByMaryvilleID(String maryvilleID) in C:\Code\MV\MV.Library\User.cs:341
   Apps.rewards.administrator.Event.btnAddAttendee_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Code\Web\Apps\Apps\rewards\administrator\Event.aspx.cs:122
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

**From what I researched**

The app is trying to store more bytes in the column than int type allows. I planned to change the table column to nvarchar or bigint but was wondering if that was all I needed to do? Would nvarchar be the better choice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your data is actually a number, then use a numeric type, e.g. bigint. you shouldn't store numbers as strings. Not unless your numbers are SO big that they overflow bigint types as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `int` max value range is `2^32` so with sign = `-2147483648` to `2147483648` or unsigned `0` to `4294967296` Your value, `9000437060`, is larger. You need a `long` which in SQL is a `BIGINT`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are overflowing an `int` with the value from the database. Try changing your c# data type to `long`